# Scrolling function working for some click events but not others

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have three variations on the same scrolling function for three different click events, the top two work fine, slowly scrolling to the element ID, however the third one just jumps straight to the element without scrolling.

```
    $('#scroll-down').click(function scrollDownProfile(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#profile').offset().top
        }, 500);
    });

    $('#scroll-down-bp').click(function scrollDownBP(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#bp').offset().top
        }, 500);
    });

    $('#scroll-down-software').click(function scrollDownProjects(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#software').offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
```

Given the fact that they are all the same, I thought it might have something to do with the HTML since each click event is on a separate page however I can't see anything wrong with the HTML below. As I said each block of HTML code is from a different page.

```
<a id="scroll-down" href="#profile" class="scroll-down">
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </header>
        <nav id="navigation-bar" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"></button>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse collapse" style="height: 1px">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li id="nav_profile" class="active">
                        <a href="#profile">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="nav_education" class>
                        <a href="#education">Education</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id = "nav_experience" class>
                        <a href="#experience">Experience</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="nav_contact" class>
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

<div id="profile" class="background_white">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Profile</h2>
            </div>
</div>
```

```
<a id="scroll-down-bp" href="#bp" class="scroll-down">
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </header>
        <nav id="navigation-bar" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse collapse" style="height: 1px">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li id="nav_bp" class="active">
                        <a href="#bp">BP-ICAM</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="nav_masters" class>
                        <a href="#masters">Master's</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id = "nav_chromition" class>
                        <a href="#chromition">Chromition</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="nav_references" class>
                        <a href="#Contact">References</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
<div id="bp" class="background_white">
            <div class="container container-about-me">
                <div id="bp-icam logo">
                    <h2>BP-ICAM</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

```
<a id="scroll-down-software" href="#software" class="scroll-down">
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </header>
<div id="software" class="background_white">
            <div class="container container-about-me">
                <h2 style="color: #2A293E;">Projects</h2>
            </div>
</div>
```

The only difference between the HTML of two that work and the the one that doesn't is the nav element between the where the user clicks and the element that is scrolled to. I don't see how this would cause a discrepancy though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd run my html through a html validator, just to be sure.
Then I'd write the click listeners like this:

```
$('#scroll-down').on('click', function {
    $('#profile')[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start"});
});
```

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView